# How to entry more than one value for a feature in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database

I have a project that is a clinical web based system, I need to save some sheet data in SQL database.

I have `"TumorSite"` table, by this table I show checkboxes that user can select one or more of them in MVC 5.
I also have `"PathologyReport"` table, I wanna to save all of the data about pathological data of a patient into it.
Some fields in `"PathologyReport"` should be complete from checkboxes that checked, some not and fill from textboxes. For checkboxes, if the user checks *"other"* another value should b saved.

How to fill multiple checkbox values for a patient? Do I need another table?
How to link `"PathologyReport"` to the new table?
What should I write in the controller in mvc?

[please see my form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SrZF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you usually need another table for that. Some SQL databases allow an "array" data type for columns (e.g. Oracle), but the usual approach is another table with a foreign key.

Comment: Thank you, but how? What should be saved from new table in "PathologyReport" for "TumorSite"?

Comment: I need to entry a feild for "TumorSite" in  "PathologyReport"? or with that relationship it desnt need?

Comment: You'd usually have some kind of primary key on the `PathologyReport` - sometihng that identifies the record. Just reference that in your new table to make it clear which report the sites belong to.

Comment: Thank you. I get what u mean. How do it in mvc? in TumorSiteController I mean. When I create my "TumoreSiteData" table, and used IDs from "TumorSite" and "PathologyReport" table in "TumoreSiteData", now should save values in TumoreSiteData.